# What is the correct way to use DolphinDB function tmbeta?

Tags: regression, least-squares, dolphindb

I want to run the script in DolphinDB:

```
T = 1..25
X = 2..26   
Y1 = 3..27
Y2 = 4..28
y_matrix = matrix(table(Y1 as y1, Y2 as y2))
y_matrix.rename!(1..25,`y1`y2).setIndexedMatrix!()
x_series = indexedSeries(1..25,X)
tmbeta(T=1..25, Y=y_matrix[0], X=x_series[0],window=10)
```

It returns an error: tmbeta(1 .. 25, y_matrix[0], x_series[0], 10) => Usage: tmbeta(T, X, Y, window). X must be a vector with the same length as T.

I’d like to calculate the coefficient estimate of an ordinary-least-squares regression of Y on X. What is the correct usage of `tmbeta`?

Answer (score 0):

For function `tmbeta`, the parameter X (y_matrix[0] in the script) must be a vector. The error is caused by the incorrect data type of y_matrix[0].

```
typestr(y_matrix[0])
FAST INT MATRIX
```

As the y_matrix is an indexed matrix in DolphinDB, you can use `mbeta`  instead of `tmbeta` as no index (T) is needed.

```
mbeta(X=x_series,Y=y_matrix,window=10)
```

The correct way to apply function `tmbeta` is:

```
y1_matrix=matrix(table(Y1 as y1, Y2 as y2))
tmbeta(T,X=x_series[0],Y=y1_matrix[0],window=10)
```

Here `y1_matrix[0]` is a vector:

```
typestr(y1_matrix[0])
FAST INT VECTOR
```